# Is there a good tool to deploy and update an iOS app that is meant to be part of a larger product?

Tags: ios, ipad, mdm, ios-enterprise, apple-configurator

I am currently working on a project that uses an iPad as the interface for the the product we are making. There is an external accessory feeding the iPad sensor data and the iPad will need to be on the business that buys our product's wifi.

The concern I have is that this doesn't really seem to fit under Apple's enterprise solution since it will not be under our own employees. Does this rule out MDM?

Apple configurator seems to be a good way of deploying these iPads and has the added benefit of preprograming stuff like the wifi of the business we are selling the product to. However, it would be preferable if the iPad was remotely configurable.

Anyways if anybody has had any experience creating such a system/workflow I would love to hear your thoughts.

Cheers!

Comment: Take a look at the [B2B](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) program.

Comment: What would you suggest I use to manage the iPads configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The B2B program is what you are looking for. https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/